# installing docx_converter gem on alpine docker image

Tags: ruby, linux, docker, rubygems

I'd like to try [docx_converter](https://github.com/michaelfranzl/docx_converter), but I'm having troubles installing in on our ruby alpine docker image,

This is my dockerfile so far, (not working).

```
FROM ruby:2.6-alpine

RUN apk add --update \
  libmagickwand-dev \
  pkgconfig imagemagick imagemagick-dev imagemagick-libs

RUN gem install docx_converter
```

it complains that  `libmagickwand-dev` doesn't exist in the apk repo.

if I remove the library from installing, the `gem install docx_converter` fails with a missing library (as expected)

the troublesome library failing seems to be ruby-filemagic-0.7.2,

with this log file (`cat /usr/local/bundle/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0/ruby-filemagic-0.7.2/mkmf.log`)

```
"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.6.0/x86_64-linux-musl -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.6.0 -I. -I/opt/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include    -O3 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wduplicated-cond -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wrestrict -Wwrite-strings -Wimplicit-fallthrough=0 -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wsuggest-attribute=format -Wsuggest-attribute=noreturn -Wunused-variable  -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -L/opt/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib -L. -fstack-protector-strong -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lruby  -lm   -lc"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */
```

I tried installing `ruby-filemagic` separately, with this dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.6-alpine

RUN apk add --update \
  pkgconfig imagemagick imagemagick-dev imagemagick-libs \
  musl libmagic file file-dev

RUN gem install ruby-filemagic

RUN gem install docx_converter
```

and get a make error

```
current directory: /usr/local/bundle/gems/ruby-filemagic-0.7.2/ext/filemagic
/usr/local/bin/ruby -I /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20200810-1-s6d76t.rb extconf.rb
checking for -lgnurx... *** extconf.rb failed ***
```

any ideas on how to get that running?

Thanks,
G

Answer (score 0):

I managed to install `ruby-filemagic` by adding the following libraries to my dockerfile:

```
RUN apk add --update \
  build-base
```

build-base is the one containing `gnurx`